# How to update a preview diff?

Tags: phabricator, arcanist

I created a preview using `arc diff --preview`.

I was wondering if I can update it using a command similar to `arc diff --update revision_number` (used for non-preview diffs)

What I tried so far:

- `arc diff --update preview_number` (error: `Usage Exception: Revision 'preview_number' does not exist!`)
- `arc diff --update Dpreview_number` (error: `Usage Exception: Revision 'preview_number' does not exist!`)
- `arc diff --update Diffpreview_number` (error: `Usage Exception: Parameter to --update must be a Differential Revision number`)

Answer (score 0):

Diff is just a change file and the unit for updating phab review updating a diff doesn't sound right. I think what you are looking for is a draft review (arc diff --draft). It will create a draft patch and you can update it as you see fit.